# duplicates in agrep function

Tags: r, agrep

I have the following code:

```
x <- data.frame("SN" = 1:2, "Name" = c("aaa","bbb"))

y <- data.frame("SN" = 1:2,  "Name" = c("aa1","aa2"))

x$partials<- as.character(sapply(x$Name, agrep, y$Name,max.distance = 1,value=T))

x
```

The output is the following:

```
    > x
  SN Name        partials
1  1  aaa c("aa1", "aa2")
2  2  bbb    character(0)
```

However I am expecting the following output:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example and fix your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for this.

First, the `sapply()` puts out nothing if `character(0)`. To prevent this, you could say it's `NA` or text `"character(0)"` if you really want this.

```
z <- setNames(sapply(x$Name, function(a) {
  ag <- agrep(a, y$Name, max.distance=1, value=TRUE)
  if (identical(ag, character(0))) NA  # set to "character(0)" at will
  else ag
  }), x$Name)
```

Then, transform the list you get into a matrix.

```
z <- do.call(rbind, z)
```

We need to `melt()` it to get the right format. A good way is with `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)
z <- setNames(melt(z)[-2], c("Name", "partials"))
```

Now, we just merge x with the new data to get the result, ensuring unique rows of `z`.

```
res <- merge(x, unique(z))[c(2, 1, 3)]

> res
  SN Name partials
1  1  aaa      aa1
2  1  aaa      aa2
3  2  bbb     <NA>
```